# Get geolocation and city name via Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, api, geolocation, analytics-api

I'd like to extract a the name of the city of a visitor and preferably also the geolocation (latitude + longitude) of those visitors.

Is this possible via the Google Analytics API and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [google reference documents](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=geo_network) for more information.

A useful tool to build a query for what you require can be located [here](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/)